# キーボードを常に表示させるためにはどうすればよいのでしょうか

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

swift初心者なのですが、SKScene上に常にキーボードを表示させる方法が知りたいです。
初歩的な質問で申し訳御座いません。宜しくお願いします。